# How to log in on API-level with django-hosts subdomain and DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-hosts

I'm using [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) (DRF) to have a browsable API which shall be available under the `api` subdomain e.g. `api.localhost:8000`. To serve subdomains, I'm using [django-hosts](https://django-hosts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
I'm having trouble to achieve login and logout functionality on API level (i.e. under the `api` subdomain).

The subdomains work but I can't get the DRF autentication mechanism to work anymore.

### Problem

Visiting `api.localhost:8000/` shows the browsable api page which is fine. The DRF Log in button is also available. Using this button shows the log-in form, but when submitting the form, I'm redirected to `http://login/` which of course can't be resolved and thus the login fails. The same applies to the logout functionality, which leads to `http://logout/` and also fails.
Below are screenshots for these steps.

### Django Settings

```
ROOT_URLCONF = "server.urls"
ROOT_HOSTCONF = "server.hosts"
DEFAULT_HOST = "api"
```

### django-hosts configuration

```
# server/hosts.py
from django_hosts import patterns, host
from django.conf import settings

host_patterns = patterns(
    '',
    host(r"api", "server.api_urls", name="api"),
    host(r"admin", "server.admin_urls", name="admin"),
    host("", settings.ROOT_URLCONF),  # resolves to server/urls.py
)
```

### URLS configuration

```
# server/urls.py
from django.urls import include, path

# this is my root url conf
urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("server.api_urls")),
    path("", include("rest_framework.urls", namespace='rest_framework')),
    path("", admin.site.urls),
]
```

I'm not happy with this, but even though I serve it at another subdomain, without adding `path("", admin.site.urls)` to the root urls conf, I always got `'admin' is not a registered namespace`. For the same reason I included `rest_framework.urls` here, because otherwise the namespace `rest_framework` was not registered.

```
# server/api_urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path("", include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),    
    path("", include("myapp.urls")),  # here is the DRF routing
]
```

In order to use the DRF authentication mechanism and the `Log in` and `Log out` button, I include the `rest_framework.urls` under the namespace I registered before. After that, the usual app urls are included which route the `users` API endpoint shown in the screenshot below.

```
# server/admin_urls.py
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path("", admin.site.urls),
]
```

### Screenshots

Visiting `api.localhost:8000/` shows the browsable api page.

[image: Page at http://api.localhost:8000/]

Using the `Log in` Button redirects to `http://api.localhost:8000/login/?next=/` which is fine.

[image: Page at ttp://api.localhost:8000/login/]

But after submitting the form, I'm redirected to `http://login/` which of course can't be resolved and thus the login fails. The same applies to the logout functionality, which leads to `http://logout/` and also fails.

[image: Login Fail]

### How can I fix the authentication mechanism to work on API-level?

Answer (score 0):

add PARENT_HOST setting.
This will make your redirect correct